# Store datetime -time only in Access database

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have a vb.net program, updating the time value in an access database. The database is connected using OleDB.

Basically this is what is happening:

```
Dim commandBuilder As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(dataEventAdapter)

eventDataset.Tables("EventList").Rows(selectedEvent)("EventTime") = Format(dateTimePick.Value, "hh:mm tt")

dataEventAdapter.Update(eventDataset, "EventList")
```

The time is taken from a datetime picker, and it should store only the time value.

The problem is, that the database already has values in it, which only has the time, like: 9:00 AM, but when I'm updating with this, it gets the date as well. And honestly I don't know where it gets the date from. If I

```
MsgBox(Format(dateTimePick.Value, "hh:mm tt"))
```

I get only the time, and nothing else.

How can I store the time only?

Comment: What is the data type of this field in Access?

Comment: And there you are. Date/time is converting your string into a date/time. Since you did not provide a date, it will do one for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the datatypes available in MS-Access you will find that there isn't a type just for Time values but there is a type for Date/Time values. This means that Access will store always the date AND the time for the values that you supply. The display that you observe looking at the MS-Access grid is controlled by the Format setting in the structure page of your table and here you could change it to show just the Time part of your data.

Said that, there is the problem that you don't supply a DateTime value, but a string. Access is gracious(?) enough to not trigger an exception for this, but compensates adding a date by itself thus you should see the current day for every value that you supply.

So you shouldn't be concerned about how your value has been displayed, but more on how you pass that value to the database. If only the time part is meaningful for your program then leaving the database engine convert back your string to a datetime value is not an option. (Without talking about the localization issues that this automation will involve)

I suggest to pass a constant value for the Date part (like DateTime.MinValue  or 1/1/1) and add your time to this value. In this way you could easily ignore the date part if you eventually need to use some queries on this data.

```
Dim dt As DateTime = new DateTime(1,1,1, dateTimePick.Value.Hour, _
                                         dateTimePick.Value.Minute,
                                         dateTimePick.Value.Second)
eventDataset.Tables("EventList").Rows(selectedEvent)("EventTime") = dt
```

Comment: Just a bit of test revelead an interesting thing. Try to pass (for the date part) the values 1899,12,30 I can't explain it but also without any particular format the access grid doesn't show the date part

Answer (score 2):

You can make a simple experiment in Access. Open the *Immediate* window with <kbd>Ctrl-G</kbd> and enter

> ?Format(#00:00:00#,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss")<kbd>Enter</kbd>
> 1899/12/30 00:00:00
>
> ?Format(#08:31:57#,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss")<kbd>Enter</kbd>
> 1899/12/30 08:31:57

The result shows you the origin Access uses for its time axis.

Another experiment shows this:

> ?#1899/12/30 08:31:57#<kbd>Enter</kbd>
> 08:31:57

Access automatically displays only the time part for the date 1899/12/30.

Therefore I suggest to use this date as a base for time-only data.

---

Access uses `Double` values to store dates internally, where the integer part represents the number of days elapsed since 1899/12/30 and the decimal fraction represents the time as fraction of 24h (i.e. 0.25 is 06:00 am and 0.75 is 18:00).

> ?CDbl(#1899/12/30 08:00:00#)<kbd>Enter</kbd>
> 0.333333333333333
>
> ?CDbl(#1899/12/30#)<kbd>Enter</kbd>
> 0
>
> ?CDate(0)<kbd>Enter</kbd>
> 00:00:00
>
> ?CDate(0.25)<kbd>Enter</kbd>
> 06:00:00

---

In .NET you can use the `System.DateTime.FromOADate(d As Double) As Date` method for the conversion of Access Dates given as `Double` to .NET Dates (VB `Date` = `System.DateTime`).

Comment: Interesting! :D I will look into it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing data types with formatting. In your database the column you are inserting into has a `datetime` datatype (Access has no data type for just time). This means that it stores everything that goes in there as a date + a time.

If in Access you are seeing values with only a time, it's likely that Access decided the date is useless (possibly because it was stored with a date of 1/1/1900).

Thing to remember is that the date still being stored. When you re-display the data just format it to only display the time. Judging from your code example you already know how to do that.

Comment: I know, it's odd. As I said, the database comes with values already. And in the "EventTime", which is a Date/Time has this data in it: "9:00 AM". And that's it. Maybe access is ignoring a date, but I can't see any date that is ignored at all! The problem was, that when I read from the database, the original values had just time in them, and what I saved, had date and time. Anyway. Steve has solved it for now! :D