# How to insert current time to a database as a datetime object?

Tags: c#, datetime, ms-access, types, datetime-format

I am trying to pass the current time. I am not interested in the date portion.

It must be passed as a DateTime object to be successfully stored in the database.

Using Microsoft access 2003 as a db
Programming language is C#
Vs2017

Comment: [This is VB.NET but it's the same idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404292/store-datetime-time-only-in-access-database)

Comment: Have you tried something like `var theTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;`?

Comment: This is similar to what john posted, but in C# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296920/how-do-you-get-the-current-time-of-day

Comment: Can you post what have you tried?

Comment: Why? Time alone  can be ambiguous without a date part.

Comment: Felipe Oriani  i have tried passing it as a string

Comment: And as using DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());

Comment: Joshmcode i have but it returns as a timespan  and will not be inserted to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found  the solution

i have setted the default value of my time column to a function called Time$()

and that will enforce the db by it self to add the current time to the new row that i will add every time automatically

if you are passing the same problem and found my answer and need more explanation just comment this answer with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should pass date time parameter to it.

```
DateTime date_today = DateTime.Now;
SqlCommand sql_command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table (date_time_table) VALUES (@value)", connection);
sql_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", date_today);
sql_command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```